# Algorithms for community discovery in multigraphs

Tags: reference-request, algorithm, clustering

In order to group unstructured or sem-structured texts for a timeline construction approach, I consider several types of correlations among such texts. These different correlations induce a weighted [multigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph), where the texts act as nodes. All edges have a normalized weight between $0$ and $1$.

I wonder what algorithms exist to find community structures within such multigraphs. The problem of community discovery in static and even dynamic graphs without multiple edges between nodes is well-studied. See e.g. [this article](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4419-8462-3_4) and [this one](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3172867?casa_token=-H2qaHBiYXkAAAAA:VFfZxKMPvqrOECbFMexKp44h-_CPfMAV_ShNOpUrI_ZzckMlabo2fOE-6o9LmGZM-sLkoEpHVjPt87c) for accounts on these respective subjects.

However, it appears that the community discovery problem on multigraphs has been studied considerably less extensively. I've found a few relevant articles on the topic, including [this 2012 paper](https://aclanthology.org/P13-3012/) by Martschat, and [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5360349?casa_token=6p4vonLbkqQAAAAA:0nXzDmGAumfN4t8wUDsHiNkPd1w0zrcr1ExbqiAjC33v-Dglt2qCbhGks_RJG-KILReGLZuWhv0l) by Tang et al. (2009) considers community discovery in multiple graphs with the same nodes.

**Question**: are there more recent community discovery algorithms that are described in the scientific literature, and include open-source code that allows one to implement the algorithm on a data set?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/161790/755